# Visual Studio Form Designer Changes Layout When Reopened Because Of MinimumSize

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, size

So I create a form layout and try to set a MinimumSize on it only to find out the WinForms has a fit!  So here is what it looks like when I start out with MinimumSize property set ONLY for the width...

[image]

As you can see it looks great, with no extra whitespace, the form is the size I want etc...
Then, I try to close the form and open it back up, I have a small oddity (the MinimumSize height was set to 0 and now WinForms has made it 38) but whatever it still works as expected..

[image]

OK well that odd "38" on the MinimumSize-Height is weird but whatever, let me try to set my prefered MinimumSize-Height to 420 (Same size as the form).

[image]

Save, Close form designer and reopen...  WTF?  Everything has gone awry!  My three buttons at the bottom have all been pushed up, so has the text box and the treeview control I have above it, as well as the left listview height has been resized.  As a matter of fact, looking at it it seems as if the controls are all the correct size still.  The variable that has changed is the form size.  It has somehow gone from 420 to 442???

[image]

Anyone have any idea why this keeps happened?  What I can do to fix it or I guess work around it?  Please keep in mind I have the buttons, and textbox anchored to the bottom.  The treeview needs to stay anchored to the top and grow with the resizing of the window.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would have been more clear.  Everything is fine until I just set a minimum size.  So there should be nothing as far as code goes.  But furthermore this is a completely a blank form with objects added to the form.  No code outside the standard designer code.  But I did notice something...  It does not happen when I add back the ControlBox.  This only happens when the ControlBox = False.  But still looking for a work around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a designer bug of course.  It is induced by a feature in Winforms that is generally a trouble-maker for the designer, it never actually stores the Size property.  Something you can see in the auto-generated code in the form's Designer.cs file.  Instead, it stores the `ClientSize` and calculates Size based on that value.  A very necessary feature, the height of the caption bar is unpredictable, it depends on user config.

What triggers the bug in your case is setting the ControlBox property to False.  That also disables the Icon and that gums up the outer size calculation.  Something to do with the order in which properties are assigned, I think, the Form class *ought* to implement ISupportInitialize but doesn't.  The value 38 for MinimumSize.Height is a side-effect, that's the height of the caption bar on your machine.  You can't make the window smaller than that.  A constraint that's also applied at design time, another quirk.

The workaround is simple.  Set ControlBox property back to True and just set its value in your Form constructor:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ControlBox = false;
    }
```

Comment: LOL, thanks!  perfect explanation.  And right after I figured out what was causing the issue!!  :)